# Why is my new file not showing up?

Tags: linux, filesystems

This is the second time i've had this occur to me.

I am working on a rails app, and I create a file via `touch show.html.haml`, and I can do an `ls` and see the file.

[image]

but I am using both WinSCP and SFTP for sublime, and neither can see this file!

WinSCP returns...
[image]

and Sublime returns,
`Downloading folder "/app/qa/www/htdocs/qa-dashboard/app/views/scripts/" ...  1 file to download`

yet it never downloads the file.  What is happening here?   I've also verified that it wasn't the `touch` command. i've tried `vi`'ing the file, and saving it.  Same thing.

I've also verified that the hosts are matching.

### Additional notes:

I am using `elevated_user` to create the file, and user, `ddavison` to edit the file.  `ddavison` is not in the group.

File modes are,

```
drwxrw-rw- ... .
drwxr-xrwx ... ..
-rw-rw-rw- ... show.html.haml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For directories, the `x` permission bit isn't execute, rather it's "list the contents of this directory". Since the directory's permissions are only 'rwxrw-rw-', only the owner may list the contents of the directory. Provide "other" that permission using `chmod o+x /app/qa/www/htdocs/qa-dashboard/app/views/scripts`.

Comment: Thanks Dan, i'm accepting your answer as it's most clear, and to the point.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The permissions on your `scripts` directory appear to be incorrect:

```
drwxrw-rw- ... .
      ^--^-- missing eXecute bit
```

The execute bit on directories allows the directory's contents to be listed. Since the "group" and "other" perms on the `scripts` directory do not allow listing, you'll get that error. Most like you're logged in to the shell as the owner of the directory, so you can get listings all you want, but you're logging in as a user OTHER than the owner via winscp, so they're unable to list the directory contents.

Answer (score 2):

I expect the problem is with the permissions on the containing directory -

```
drwxrw-rw- ... .
```

Both of those programs probably try to chdir into that directory before retrieving the file. In order to do so, the directory must have x (execute) permissions for the user they are logging in as. Based on what you said, it seems that set 'other' needs +x -

```
chmod o+x /app/qa/www/htdocs/qa-dashboard/app/views/scripts/
```

Depending on the users/groups in question, you may want to consider removing write permission -

```
chmod o-w /app/qa/www/htdocs/qa-dashboard/app/views/scripts/
```